# Add master_checkbox into group bar of dhtmlx

Tags: dhtml, dhtmlx

I want to put my master checkbox into the group bar of dhtmlXGrid. I just write a new `stat_checkbox` like

```
dhtmlXGridObject.prototype._g_stat_checkbox=function(c,n,i){
  return !!n;
}
```

and use it inside group bar like

```
my_grid.groupBy(2,["#title","","","","","#stat_checkbox"])
```

But I don't know how to make my master checkbox can work like `_in_header_master_checkbox`
There is 2 issues here

```
1. Because of _g_stat_checkbox return n, so when I click on my master checkbox, the eXcell_ch() be called. How can I cancel this event?
2. How to check all grid in only this group?
```

Is there any solution for my issue?